# MYSQL - How come when I made changes on my schema (I misspelled a word) it didn't update the local instance even after saving and restarting?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

How do I show the changes made on my schema on the local instance? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You often need to actually refresh your schema. If you are building it from the code editor side and migrating and you don't have any data in it yet, it's never a bad idea to just dump it and start fresh though. Are you in a situation where you are making migrations and expecting to see the changes?[sample schema right-click refresh option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqR57.png)

Comment: Got it to work! Fixing it right on the local instance did the trick instead. I had no idea that was possible.